# SQL getting multiple rows in PARTICULAR sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `abc` with following rows:

```
emp_id_role     Group_name              Role_name       Location_id
 12              Insurance              Manager            Noida
 12              Insurance              Senior Manager     Noida
 13       Global Client Services            Sw               UP
 14       Operations Management         All Jobs           kERALA
```

and another master table with all the details `employee_xyz`:

```
PERSON_ID   NAME        DOB     START_DATE      END_DATE        SSN
  12        DEAN    01-JAN-1990 01-JAN-2017     20-JAN-2017     847474
  12        DEAN    01-JAN-1990 21-JAN-2017     03-mar-2018     847474
  12        DEAN    01-JAN-1990 04-mar2018      31-DEC-4712     847474
  13        SAM     20-JAN-1990 17-JAN-2016     20-JAN-2017     847474
  13        SAM     20-JAN-1990 21-JAN-2017     31-DEC-4712     847474
  14        JAY     29-dec-1990 21-JAN-2016     31-DEC-4712     847474
```

I want to fetch the full names from the table `employee_xyz` for the records in table `abc`.

When I'm joining these two using the below queries I'm getting more number of rows for an employee than in table `abc`,

Eg: for `employee_id 12` I should get 2 rows as in table `abc` but I'm getting 9 rows somehow...

Query used is simple :

```
select * from table_abc abc,
employee_xyz xyz
where xyz.person_id=abc.emp_id_role
and trunc(sysdate) between abc.Start_date and xyz.end_date
and person_id=12;
```

Comment: Your query should get four rows, not nine. Both rows in `abc` for role 12 are joined to both date-matched rows in `xyz` for role 12, so that's expected?

Comment: Before the edit, you had two different names against person_id 12; forpas has changed that... with the current data (which looks more sensible) you do only get two rows back. You need to show us data that actually demonstrates the issue you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to select all columns from `table_abc` with names from `employee_xyz`.

If your try with `select abc.*, xyz.name`, you already able to select as two rows since `sysdate` for *person_id= 12* stays in the interval only for third row(*start_date:04-mar2018/ end_date:31-DEC-4712*) but if you want non-repeating even with more date values stay, you can use distinct : `select distinct abc.*, xyz.name` as below( *where there're two rows in the interval second row's end date  converted from '2018-03-03' to '2019-03-03'* ) :

```
with table_abc(emp_id_role, Group_name, Role_name, Location_id) as
(
 select 12,'Insurance','Manager','Noida' from dual union all
 select 12,'Insurance','Senior Manager','Noida' from dual union all
 select 13,'Global Client Services','Sw', 'UP' from dual union all
 select 14,'Operations Management','All Jobs','kERALA' from dual
),
    employee_xyz(person_id,name, dob, start_date, end_date, ssn) as
(
 select 12,'DEAN',date'1990-01-01',date'2017-01-01',date'2017-01-20',847474 from dual union all        
 select 12,'DEAN',date'1990-01-01',date'2017-01-21',date'2019-03-03',847474 from dual union all        
 select 12,'DEAN',date'1990-01-01',date'2018-03-04',date'4712-12-31',847474 from dual      
)
select distinct abc.*, xyz.name
  from table_abc abc join employee_xyz xyz
    on xyz.person_id = abc.emp_id_role
 where trunc(sysdate) between xyz.Start_date and xyz.end_date
   and person_id = 12;

EMP_ID_ROLE GROUP_NAME  ROLE_NAME         LOCATION_ID  NAME
----------- ----------  ---------------  -----------   -----
12          Insurance   Manager           Noida        DEAN
12          Insurance   Senior Manager    Noida        DEAN
```